# How can I accept different types of payloads and cast them to the corresponding AVRO schema in Kotlin?

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, avro, micronaut

I have a Kotlin (Micronaut) [ServerWebSocket](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/websocket/annotation/ServerWebSocket.html) which receives different types of payloads.
These payloads all have a `topic` property which corresponds with a Kafka topic, which expects a specific type of AVRO schema.
With the incoming topic string I can retrieve the right AVRO schema and the class that's been built for it.

In the way I've implemented it now, it can receive everything, however I can't seem to cast it to the right class, as I get the error: `Cannot cast java.util.LinkedHashMap to ExampleOne`

```
data class WSMessage <T> (val topic: String, val payload: T)

@ServerWebSocket("/ws")
class WebSocket(...) {

    @OnMessage
    fun <T> onMessage(session: WebSocketSession, message: WSMessage<T>) {
        val payload = validate(message)
    }
    
    private fun <T> validate(msg: WSMessage<T>): SpecificRecord? {
        val schema = topics.find { it.topic == msg.topic }?.schema ?: throw NullPointerException("Topic '${msg.topic}' is unknown")
        val schemaClass = Class.forName(schema)

        // ERROR: Cannot cast java.util.LinkedHashMap to PersonalMessage
        val test = schemaClass.cast(msg.payload)

        return test
    }

}
```

As the incoming type `T` is basically the same as `Any`, I can't get it to work like this.
It works perfectly fine however, if I specify that I'm expecting param `message: WSMessage<ExampleOne>`, it will automatically turn message into a `WSMessage<ExampleOne>` for me without any issues.

However this is only useful if I will only be receiving payloads of type `ExampleOne`, whereas I will be receiving payloads with different types, so it should also support `ExampleTwo` and any other classes I specify.
The most optimal solution would be it accepting any [SpecificRecord](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/specific/SpecificRecord.html), which is the type every AVRO schema class implements, however changing it to take `<T: SpecificRecord>` doesn't help.

Is there some other type I can replace the incoming type `T` with, so I can later on cast it to the right type? Or is there a way for me to define the different possible types so it knows it should be either one of those?

A messy solution I have found for this is to make different function overloads by using the @JvmName annotation, but that's not foolproof at all as I found that even changing the order of the different functions can break it. And the could would become a big mess.